# jQuery hide() not working

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, hide

I am trying to hide a dropdown (select element) using hide but not able to. Below is the jQuery code I am using.

```
$('.myClass').find('select[name=xyz]').hide();
```

**Exception in chrome : object xyz has no method 'hide'**

---

Corresponding HTML

```
<div class="myClass">
        <select id="xyz" name="xyz">
                    <option>option1</option>
                    <option>option2</option>
                    </select>
        <select id="123" name="123">
                    <option>option3</option>
                    <option>option4</option>
                    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just: `$('#xyz').hide();`?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** I see that you have now edited the HTML in your post and added the `name` attribute that was originally missing.  Your HTML and javascript works for me in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/qaJff/) so if it isn't working for you then it's because you have something else wrong in your page or duplicate IDs or something like that.  Even so, I suggest you just use the simpler form that I suggest below as it's simpler, faster and more foolproof.

**Previous Answer Before OP was edited:**

I see no `name` attribute for you to match.  If you want to get the `select` tag with the `xyz` id, then use this:

```
$("#xyz").hide();
```

IDs much be unique in the page so you can just address it directly, no need to do all the other stuff to find it.  If you were doing it the way you were because your IDs weren't unique in the page, then you have to fix that as you will get unpredictable results in different browsers with conflicting IDs.

Comment: I missed it in the post, actually name was there

Comment: Still, use the ID as we suggested.  It's much faster and will work.  Actually, your new version of the HTML seems to work just fine for me with your code in Chrome.  See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/qaJff/

Comment: IDs are unique. I can read the attributes using $("#xyz").attr("id") but only the method hide() is not working.

Comment: @void1916 - Did you try my jsFiddle example?  It seems to work fine in chrome there for me  Or does that not work for you either?

Comment: @jfriend00 .. Yes I checked the jsFiddle and it works there but not on my application .. weird :(

Comment: Then, you will have to show us the rest of your HTML because something else in your HTML (that you haven't shown us) is conflicting with the selector.

Comment: @void1916 - Ahhh - here's my guess.  Are you calling the code before the page has finished loading (and thus the elements don't exist yet)?  You would need to call this code inside `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 .. No I verified that, I can read attributes using `alert($('#xyz').attr("id"))` at the same place. Anyway if I try to hide the parent using `$('#xyz').parent().hide()` it hides the parent.

Comment: As I said, we'd have to see the rest of your HTML to offer more ideas.  It's something to do with the rest of your page or code.

Answer (score 0):

there's no `[name=xyz]`

change it to id

```
$('.myClass #xyz').hide();
```

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/1acce/1

Comment: OP edited to add Name but it doesn't work with neither ID or Name in my application

Answer (score 0):

You have the id of the select labeled xyz.

```
$('.myClass').find('select#xyz').hide();
```

Or Better yet

```
$('#xyz').hide();
```

The [jQuery [attribute=value]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector searches for the specific attribute.

The [jQuery id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) will search the id of the element.

Comment: Why all that extra stuff when all you need is `$("#xyz").hide();`?  It's an id.  They are directly addressable and unique in the page.

Answer (score 0):

you have no name in your select

```
$('.myClass #xyz').hide();
```

you have to add the name if you ever plan to submit that. Final, note: IDs and attributes in general shall not start with a number, but with a letter.

```
<div class="myClass">
        <select name="xyz" id="xyz">
                    <option>option1</option>
                    <option>option2</option>
                    </select>
        <select name="abc" id="abc">
                    <option>option3</option>
                    <option>option4</option>
                    </select>
</div>
```